# Convex set with convex complement has non empty interior?

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is if in a normed space (maybe complete if necessary), a convex (non empty) set with convex complement has non-empty interior.

I cannot think of a counterexample, but neither how to prove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an unbounded functional $\ell$ and consider
$$
A = \{ x \in X \mid \ell(x) \le 0 \}.
$$
The complement
$$
B = \{ x \in X \mid \ell(x) > 0 \}
$$
is convex as well and neither of these sets have an nonempty interior.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted! This answer is a bit terse, but it seems correct to me. I believe the missing steps are "any infinite-dimensional normed space admits an unbounded linear functional", and "the kernel of an unbounded functional is dense" - so all the fibres are dense. Hence these two complementary convex subsets are both dense, so each must have empty interior (giving a counterexample in any infinite-dimensional space). These facts are fairly well-known I think, and proofs can be found on this site.